# How to add multiple trendlines to a scatter plot by groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, trendline, aesthetics

I'm trying to add multiple trendlines to a scatter plot in ggplot by age groups. I have 4 `Age_range`'s `20_under`, `21_24`, `25_29`, and `30_up` so I'm looking to have 4 trendlines for each of these age groups

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot( cars, aes( x = horsepower, y = miles, color = Age_range))+ 
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method=lm)+
    stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 77, label.y = -3000)
```

I've hit a total roadblock. I tried working off a couple of similar questions on Stack Overflow but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you clarify (1) which `cars` dataset you are using? The inherent datasets just has speed and distribution - ensuring this question is reproducible would be super helpful (2) what package `stat_cor` comes from? Thanks and good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith This actually isn't a public data set unfortunately. stat_cor comes from ggpubr

Comment: I assumed that you cannot show the stats properly, but it'd be much better if you clarify what do you mean by *"I've hit a total roadblock."* and include details on what errors or not desired outputs you are getting exactly. Please [edit] the question and share those details there, as comments get less attention. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `aes(color = ...)` inside `stat_cor` as well or set `inherit.aes = TRUE`. Also, don't provide both `label.x` and `label.y` in `stat_cor` as that would cause the labels to print over each other when you have multiple groups.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

## creating a sample dataset
set.seed(9)
MPG_Sample <- mpg[mpg$manufacturer %in% 
                    sample(unique(mpg$manufacturer), size = 4), ]

ggplot(MPG_Sample, aes(x = cty, y = displ, color = manufacturer))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, formula = y ~ x) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 25, aes(color = manufacturer))
# stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 25, inherit.aes = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The plot can be also created using package 'ggpmisc'. This is an alternative answer.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

## creating a sample dataset
set.seed(9)
MPG_Sample <- mpg[mpg$manufacturer %in% 
                    sample(unique(mpg$manufacturer), size = 4), ]

# using ggpmisc instead of ggpubr
ggplot(MPG_Sample, aes(x = cty, y = displ, color = manufacturer)) + 
  geom_point()+
  stat_poly_line() +
  stat_correlation(use_label(c("R", "P")), label.x = "right")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-27 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>